# How do you know how to limit how many client that could enter your basic group chat app server? (Maximum 10)

Tags: java

so here is my code :
Server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class Server implements Runnable{
            Socket connectionSocket;     
            public static Vector clients=new Vector();
            public Server(Socket s){
                    try{
                            System.out.println("Client Got Connected  " );
                            connectionSocket=s;
                    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }     
            public void run(){
                    try{
                            BufferedReader reader =
                                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
                            BufferedWriter writer= 
                                            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream()));

                            clients.add(writer); 

                        while(true){
                            String data1 = reader.readLine().trim();
                            System.out.println("Received : "+data1);      

                            for (int i=0;i<clients.size();i++){
                               try{
                                    BufferedWriter bw= (BufferedWriter)clients.get(i);
                                    bw.write(data1);
                                    bw.write("\r\n");
                                    bw.flush();
                                }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception{
            System.out.println("Threaded Chat Server is Running  " );
            ServerSocket mysocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
                while(true){
                Socket sock = mysocket.accept();
                Server server=new Server(sock);
                Thread serverThread=new Thread(server);
                serverThread.start();
                }
            }
}
```

mychat.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class mychat implements Runnable
{
    public JTextField tx;
    public JTextArea ta;

    public String login="Imed";

    BufferedWriter writer;
    BufferedReader reader;

    public mychat(String l)
    {
        login=l;        
        ClientName z = new ClientName();
        JFrame f=new JFrame(z.getName()+"'s Chat");
        f.setSize(400,400);        

        JPanel p1=new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel p2=new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());        

        tx=new JTextField();
        p1.add(tx, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton b1=new JButton("Send");
        p1.add(b1, BorderLayout.EAST); 

        ta=new JTextArea();
        p2.add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p2.add(p1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        f.setContentPane(p2);



        try
        {
                 Socket socketClient= new Socket("localhost",5555);
                 writer= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketClient.getOutputStream()));

                 reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));




        }

        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
            {
                String s=login+" : "+tx.getText();  
                tx.setText("");
                try
                {
                    writer.write(s);
                    writer.write("\r\n");
                    writer.flush(); 
                }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
          }
        );

        f.setVisible(true);    


    }
    public void run()
    {
             try
             {
                String serverMsg=""; 
                while((serverMsg = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("from server: " + serverMsg);
                    ta.append(serverMsg+"\n");
                }
             }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

startclient.java

```
public class startclient
{

        public static void main(String [] args)
        {

                   try
                   {

                            ClientName n = new ClientName();
                            mychat c=new mychat(n.getName());   
                            Thread t1=new Thread(c);
                            t1.start();
                    }
           catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        }
    }
```

And last ClientName.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class ClientName 
{
    String name;

    public String getName() 
    {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print ("Enter your name : ");
     name = sc.nextLine();
     return name; 
    }
}
```

So basically, i want to limit how many client that could join my server(which maximum is 10 client). And if there is another client that want to join the server after it is full, that client will be rejected so it cannot joined. 
I think that's it, though if there are any other improvement in other areas at my code it will also be appreciated. Sorry for my bad english

*Oh and sorry since I forget to include it, but somehow when I start the client, it ask the name twice

Comment: Oh and sorry since I forget to include it, but somehow when I start the client, it ask the name twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix `main` method in your server and add `sayGoodBye()` as follows:

```
private static final int CONNECTION_LIMIT = 10;

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Threaded Chat Server is Running  ");
    ServerSocket mysocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
    int socketCount = 0;
    while (true) {
        Socket sock = mysocket.accept();
        Server server = new Server(sock);
        if (socketCount++ < CONNECTION_LIMIT) {
            Thread serverThread = new Thread(server);
            serverThread.start();
         } else {
            // without starting a thread and notifying only new client
            server.sayGoodbye();  
         }
    }
}

public void sayGoodbye() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream()))) {
        writer.write("Sorry, new client connections are not accepted, bye for now");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    connectionSocket.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I think the only thing that i need to do is to fix why the client is asking the name twice when I run it. I forget to include it too, anyway thank you so much for your help again

Comment: I know it's pretty late. I found a problem, let's say that the server already full of client, which then decline any new client that wants to join to the server. But even though I already close some client to make room for the new one. It still rejecting another new client, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Thank you kindly for unaccepting my previous answer and dropping my reputation!  Of course, there are different ways of tracking active clients on the server side.  Normally, the client should notify the server that it's going to logout/exit/quit whatever, and then the server updates the list of active clients/connections.  Additionally, both client and server may submit `ping`/`heartbit` signals - and the server tracks the timeout between the client signals and is able to catch IOException when sending its `pings` and also remove stale connections.